# C: field has incomplete type

Tags: c, makefile

I apologise if this has been previously asked.

I am getting the following error while compiling through make:

```
.../inc/intModIp.h:418: error: field 'cnc_id' has incomplete type
../inc/intModIp.h:419: error: field 'cnc_key' has incomplete type
../inc/intModIp.h:421: error: field 'fin_id' has incomplete type
../inc/intModIp.h:422: error: field 'fin_key' has incomplete type
../inc/intModIp.h:424: error: field 'remote_id' has incomplete type
../inc/intModIp.h:426: error: field 'cnc_ipsec_peer' has incomplete type
../inc/intModIp.h:427: error: field 'fin_ipsec_peer' has incomplete type
../inc/intModIp.h:428: error: field 'remote_ipsec_peer' has incomplete type
../inc/intModIp.h:430: error: field 'cnc_link' has incomplete type
../inc/intModIp.h:431: error: field 'cnc_esp' has incomplete type
../inc/intModIp.h:433: error: field 'fin_link' has incomplete type
../inc/intModIp.h:434: error: field 'fin_esp' has incomplete type
```

Respective code in the header file is as follows:

```
#if 1 || defined(SYMB_IPSEC)
    struct ipsec_state {
        int enabled;
        int active;
        int timer;
/* IPSEC_SOCKET_STATES */

        struct ipsec_id cnc_id;
        struct ipsec_priv_key cnc_key;

        struct ipsec_id fin_id;
        struct ipsec_priv_key fin_key;

        struct ipsec_id remote_id;

        struct ipsec_peer cnc_ipsec_peer;
        struct ipsec_peer fin_ipsec_peer;
        struct ipsec_peer remote_ipsec_peer;

        struct ipsec_ike_link cnc_link;
        struct ipsec_esp_sa cnc_esp;

        struct ipsec_ike_link fin_link;
        struct ipsec_esp_sa fin_esp;
    } ipsec;
#endif
```

could someone please help me with this. 
Please let me know if any other information is required.

Thanks, 
Sunny

Comment: It appears that you need to include the header that declares each of those structures.

Comment: Seems like `struct ipsec_id` and others declared after `struct ipsec_state` or not declared at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem could be that all those structs are declared forward.

Is header included after `struct ipsec_state`?:

/* a.h */

```
struct a {
    int i;
};
```

/* demo.c */

```
struct b {
    struct a A;
};

#include "a.h"

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
david@debian:~$ gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -W -Wextra -o demo demo.c
demo.c:2:11: error: field ‘A’ has incomplete type
```

Answer (score 4):

Compiler can not find stated struct definitions (`ipsec_id`  ... `ipsec_esp_sa` ), you may need to include related header files

Comment: Make sure inclusion of header is not guarded by some MACRO definition.something like #if IPSEC

Answer (score 1):

One source of that error (field has incomplete type) is when you use the struct keyword in front of an *alias* (a variable defined through typedef). Try removing the struct keyword.

Answer (score -1):

put pointer for structure member.

```
struct ipsec_state {
        int enabled;
        int active;
        int timer;
/* IPSEC_SOCKET_STATES */

        struct ipsec_id *cnc_id;
        struct ipsec_priv_key *cnc_key;

        struct ipsec_id *fin_id;
        struct ipsec_priv_key *fin_key;

        struct ipsec_id *remote_id;

        struct ipsec_peer *cnc_ipsec_peer;
        struct ipsec_peer *fin_ipsec_peer;
        struct ipsec_peer *remote_ipsec_peer;

        struct ipsec_ike_link *cnc_link;
        struct ipsec_esp_sa *cnc_esp;

        struct ipsec_ike_link *fin_link;
        struct ipsec_esp_sa *fin_esp;
    } ipsec;
#endif
```