# C error: parameter has incomplete type

Tags: c

I am a relatively new C programmer, so please bear with my ignorance :-)
I am trying to get a custom tool for valgrind to compile. The tool was originally written about 8 years ago, and was based on a much older version of valgrind. The original version of valgrind no longer compiles on current kernels, so I am trying to integrate the custom tool with the latest version of valgrind from the svn repository.

I have a very persistent problem in that I keep getting a message saying that:
`error: parameter xxxx has an incomplete type`

I read the post at: [make - C: field has incomplete type - Stack Overflow][[C: field has incomplete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291268/c-field-has-incomplete-type])
and have verified that the include file is indeed being included in the c program.

I suspect it has more to do with the fact that the definition of the struct has changed over time:

***old code***

```
typedef struct _VgHashTable * VgHashTable;

/* Make a new table.  Allocates the memory with VG_(calloc)(), so can
   be freed with VG_(free)().  The table starts small but will
   periodically be expanded.  This is transparent to the users of this
   module. */
extern VgHashTable VG_(HT_construct) ( HChar* name );
```

***new code ***

```
typedef struct _VgHashTable VgHashTable;

/* Make a new table.  Allocates the memory with VG_(calloc)(), so can
   be freed with VG_(free)().  The table starts small but will
   periodically be expanded.  This is transparent to the users of this
   module. The function never returns NULL. */
extern VgHashTable *VG_(HT_construct) ( const HChar* name );
```

The code that accesses the VgHashTable is:

```
static Int ca_count_hashtable( VgHashTable table )
```

How can I change the code to be able to correctly use the new definition of VgHashTable?

Comment: Sorry the code formatting didn't work as I expected. Any tips on how to format code also appreciated.

Comment: where is your `struct _VgHashTable` defined?

Comment: @dnraikes Read the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

If you want `ca_count_hashtable` to work with `VgHashTable` instead of `VgHashTable *`, you need the actual `struct _VgHashTable {...};` lines before `ca_count_hashtable` is declared because the compiler doesn't know what `struct _VgHashTable` contains at that point (what its size is, what its members are, etc.)

An example of what I mean:

```
struct Foo;

int Foo_n(struct Foo f) { return f.n; }

// Needs to be moved before "Foo_n" for "Foo_n" to work!
struct Foo { int n; };
```

Because `Foo_n` has no idea what members `struct Foo` has, it can't determine the size of the structure (including structure padding), the offsets of the members to access them in memory, etc.  Unless you fully define the type before the function is declared, you can't do anything with objects of that type.  You can, of course, declare the function to require a pointer to an object of that type, but the function cannot access any members of the structure object until the type is fully defined.  In other words, this is invalid:

```
/*
 * Foo.h
 */
struct Foo;
int Foo_n(struct Foo *); //Pointers to incomplete types are OK in declarations.

/*
 * Foo.c
 */
#include "Foo.h"

int Foo_n(struct Foo *f)
{
    /*
     * Invalid: does "struct Foo" contain a member named "n"?  Where is it located
     * (relative to the beginning of the structure)?
     */
    return f->n;
}

struct Foo { int n; }; //"Foo_n" needs me, but I'm stuck down here.  Please move me?
```

But this is valid:

```
/*
 * Foo.h
 */
struct Foo;
int Foo_n(struct Foo *); //Pointers to incomplete types are OK in declarations.

/*
 * Foo.c
 */
#include "Foo.h"

struct Foo { int n; }; //"Foo_n" can use me!  I'm so happy I moved!

int Foo_n(struct Foo *f)
{
    return f->n;
}
```